# How to pass a variable value in a FROM clause in Microsoft TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

sorry I am uploading a pic of my query as I dont know to format my text...as a newbie its confusing.

[image: querypic]

Comment: just paste in text, way better than an image. There is a button on the toolbar `{}` which indents code 4 characters from the left.

Comment: also: you **cannot** pass in a table name as a variable, unless you build what is know as "dynamic sql" which is: *sql that produces sql*

Answer (score 0):

So you want to execute:

```
select * from File_20170703 -- where your table name is a variable.
```

It is not possible to use variables for table or column names, what you need to do is to build a dynamic sql and execute it using sp_executesql.

here is an example:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM File_20170703'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

[More info about dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

A simple TSQL "dynamic sql" looks like this:

```
DECLARE @file_name  AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @file_name = 'file_20170101'

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @file_name

execute(@query)
```

Basically you need to create a valid sql query by concatenating various parts of the query together, then you can execute that whole big string as your query.

Answer (score -2):

You can use SQL Cursor along with while loop. Examples are given here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql